# Trying to find this specific character "|" location in a string

Tags: r

I'm trying to find this specific character `"|"` location in a string.

for example: `8,75.2|6,0.376`
the answer I expect is `7`

I trying to use regexpr:

```
 regexpr('|',"8,75.2|6,0.376")
```

but it didn't worked  (although it did work to when I looked for the ",")

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The '|' character is a special character in regular expression. You can search for a '|' by using the escape character '\' `regexpr("\\|","8,75.2|6,0.376")`

Comment: Actually in `r` it should be `regexpr("\\|","8,75.2|6,0.376")`

Comment: @Jacob. You really should fix the error that was identified.

Comment: I updated my answer to properly nullify the special character

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `lapply`:

```
> str <- '8,75.2|6,0.376'
> chars <- strsplit(str, '')
> chars
[[1]]
[1] "8" "," "7" "5" "." "2" "|" "6" "," "0" "." "3" "7" "6"
> loc <- lapply(chars, function(elem) which (elem == '|'))
> loc
[[1]]
[1] 7
```

See the [lapply documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.0/topics/lapply)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
str_locate("8,75.2|6,0.376",fixed('|'))
#or
str_locate("8,75.2|6,0.376",'\\|')
```

sample result:

```
     start end
[1,]     7   7
```